# Chart rendering issue when hiding all series via clicking on legends

Tags: highcharts

Steps to reproduce.

1. We have a chart that display 4 series of data, and we have the corresponding legends with each series.
2. THe initial chart is loaded with 1 years worth of data.
3. We then remove all data-series from the chart by clicking on the 4 legends
4. We then change the Zoom level of the chart - e.g. going from a 6 month zoom, to a 3 month zoom.  (NOTE: We change Zoom with no data-series being displayed).
5. We then re-enable the data-series by clicking on the legends.
6. The chart does not redraw correctly.  To get the chart to redraw we have to reload the entire page.

   ```
          <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
         <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 600px"> </div>

          $(function() {
              var seriesOptions = [],
              yAxisOptions = [],
              seriesCounter = 0,
              names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'],
              colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

       $.each(names, function(i, name) {
           $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',   function(data) {
               seriesOptions[i] = {
                   name: name,
                   data: data
               };

               // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
               // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
               seriesCounter++;
               if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
                   createChart();
               }
           });
       });

       // create the chart when all data is loaded
       function createChart() {
           chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
               chart: {
                   renderTo: 'container'
               },
               navigator: {
                               enabled: false
                           },
               legend: {
                               enabled: true
                           },

           rangeSelector: {
               selected: 4
           },
           scrollbar: {
                           enabled: false
                       },
           yAxis: {
               labels: {
                   formatter: function() {
                       return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                   }
               },
               plotLines: [{
                   value: 0,
                   width: 2,
                   color: 'silver'
               }]
           },

           plotOptions: {
               series: {
                   compare: 'percent'
               }
           },

           tooltip: {
               pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
               valueDecimals: 2
           },
           series: seriesOptions
       });
   }
   ```

   });

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/leewadhams/FDXBu/)

Comment: It works if you change zoom level to All from 3 month zoom.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, so I've reported it to our devs here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1568

Answer (score 0):

**A simple workaround** :
After some trial and error, I found out that if you do not disable the navigator, the above bug is not exhibited. (Navigator is enabled by default.)

Comment the line as shown below:

```
navigator: {
     //enabled: false
}
```

Js Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/msjaiswal/FDXBu/1/

Certainly this is a bug in Highcharts but we can live with this above simple workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in version [1.3.2](http://www.highcharts.com/downloads/zips/Highstock-1.3.2.zip) of HighStock.